# Problema al instalar python-Levenshtein

Tags: python, powershell, anaconda, pip

Intento instalar python-Levenshtein desde Anaconda Powershell con el siguiente código:

```
pip install python-Levenshtein
```

y me arroja un error bastante largo y al final:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

No es la primera ves que me pasa, también al intentar instalar mysql-python me sucede lo mismo.

¿Alguien me puede orientar?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-levenshtein
```

Si no, baja e instala la versión que corresponda en [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-levenshtein](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#python-levenshtein)